# Will there be any documentation for the "XBF" binary XAML format?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

At Build, it was announced that Xaml will be compiled. This affects my work quite a bit. We do work reading and modifying XAML files inside of Appx packages. So, I downloaded the previews and made a quick sample application and indeed, no XAML file in sight. Instead, I have this strange `.xbf` file for each XAML page. Using a hex editor I can see familiar things like XML namespaces for XAML, but this does not appear to be anything like BAML, so there is basically no documentation for it. A completely new format.

Has (or will) Microsoft release some form of documentation about this new binary XAML format?

Comment: Reposting Tim Heuer's response as a question: What is the use case for needing the format?

Comment: @LarryOsterman primarily for making tool(s) for analysis and rewriting of XAML.

Answer (score 3):

There are no plans to provide documentation on the format. An API exists to create the format. If you are a tool or some other intermediate process, you can instruct your developers to turn off XBF generation (in the proj file DisableXbfGeneration=true) and then do your intermediate work, then you'd be responsible for generating the XBF in your process.

Comment: By the API do you mean XamlBinaryWriter? The problem with that class is that it only works in Store app. Most tools are desktop applications written in WPF or Windows Forms. How to perform XAML to XBF compilation in desktop application.

Comment: @Jaska it seems you can use [`XamlBinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbinarywriter) from Windows 8.1 desktops and above.

Answer (score 3):

This tool (http://xamldecompiler.codeplex.com/) allows you to dig into the format.  It was just a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft will eventually have to publish the details or else face the fact that they once again have an unfair advantage with their tooling relative to other developer tool vendors.  Until then, reflection is your best friend, but they did seem to try a little harder to make this difficult to dig into for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a6873d4c-4ac2-4b07-b7b9-99cab2db43f7/convert-xbf-to-xaml?forum=winappswithcsharp) last month there is no support for loading xbf files so you'll have to load your objects with Application.LoadComponent, convert to XAML with XamlWriter, make your changes and then save out to xbf with XamlBinaryWriter.